# Use aggregate functions with group by from several tables

Tags: mysql, database, datatables, left-join, aggregate-functions

I have the following tables to allow the subscriber to sell products through the application

Order Table

| OrderId | Date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-10 |
| 2 | 2021-08-24 |

Approval table

| ApprovalId | OrderId | Status | SellerId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Accepted | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | Rejected | 20 |
| 3 | 2 | Accepted | 30 |

Item table

| ItemId | OrderId | Price | Qty | SellerId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 620$ | 1 | 10 |
| 2 | 1 | 150$ | 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 1 | 410$ | 1 | 20 |
| 4 | 2 | 220$ | 1 | 30 |

what i want is to display the income revenue for > **only who accept the order**

| Date | Sales | Seller_Part 90% | Net_Sales 10% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-10 | 770$ | 693$ | 77$ |
| 2021-08-24 | 220$ | 198% | 22$ |

I tried using aggregate functions with group by but the result include rejected order also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select o.date
  ,sum(i.price * i.qty) sales 
  ,sum(i.price * i.qty) * 0.90 Seller_Part90% 
  ,sum(i.price * i.qty) * 0.10 Net_Sales10% 
from Order o
join Approval a 
  on o.orderId = a.OrderId
  and a.status= 'Accepted'
join Items i
 on a.sellerid = i.sellerid  
 and a.orderid = i.orderid
group by o.date
```

Comment: Right answer, Thank you four your help :)